# Is this "AND" implementation safe against side channel attacks?

Tags: algorithm-design, implementation, side-channel-attack

I found out that the following is a working implementation of calculating an AND function between XOR masked shares, implementation at [Github](https://github.com/feketebv/Side_channel_attack_countermeasures/tree/master/masked_AND_by_me). It works by calculating parities, whose terms cancel each other out in a "lucky" way whenever an odd number of shares is used.

The primary advantage of this algorithm could be that parity has the property that it can be easily updated by XOR-ing any term to be taken out and add any new term needed thus decreasing the number of computations both in XORs and finally ANDs as well.

```
def masked_AND(shares, a_masked, b_masked, random):
    
    # calculate AND between shares...
    c_masked = [a_masked[i] & b_masked[i] for i in range(shares)]
    # ...with refreshing the output's mask 
    c_masked = [c_masked[i] ^ random[i] for i in range(shares)]
    
    # calculating correction terms: some terms of the parities'
    # cancel out at the end in case of an odd number of elements
    for i in range(shares):
        parity_a = 0
        parity_b = 0
        # calculating parities of all corresponding Aj and Bj bits...
        for j in range(shares):
            # ...corresponding means all but the Ai and Bi bits
            if i!=j:
                parity_a ^= a_masked[j]
                parity_b ^= b_masked[j]

        # addig correction term to the particular output share
        # which is the "AND" between the parities
        c_masked[i] ^= parity_a & parity_b
    return c_masked
```

My primary concern is: is it safe to calculate the parities of all but 1 of the shares one after the other? Can you give me hints on other problems maybe - for example for some reason in the ISW-scheme $(a[i] \wedge  b[i])$ are not refreshed but every other combination $(a[i] \wedge b[j]) \ where \ i\neq j$ is?

Comment: https://github.com/feketebv/Side_channel_attack_countermeasures/tree/master/masked_AND_by_me

Comment: Specifically https://github.com/feketebv/Side_channel_attack_countermeasures/blob/master/masked_AND_by_me/and_w_randomness.py

Comment: I've edited your question, could you check that, especially the equations.